# set to responsive an image in the fancybox

Tags: jquery

works fine in my laptop screen, but i need `responsive` to work fine in smartphones and tablets. I mean: responsive

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.fancybox({
   'width': '800px',
   'height': '286px',
   'autoScale': true,
   'transitionIn': 'fade',
   'transitionOut': 'fade',
   'type': 'image',
   'href': 'style/images/banner.jpg'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.fancybox({
   'max-width': '800px',
   'min-width': '200px',
   'max-height': '286px',
   'min-height': '200px',
   'autoScale': true,
   'transitionIn': 'fade',
   'transitionOut': 'fade',
   'type': 'image',
   'href': 'style/images/banner.jpg'
});
```

Edit the values as per your desire.